# How To Extract Words From Domain Name String

Tags: php, string, dictionary

For any domain name example for `microsoft.com` or `mainsoft.com` how do I divide it into two words?

say `mico` and `soft`, `main` and `soft`

I am talking about any domains...like `stackoverflow.com` it should be `stack`, `over`, and `flow`

How can this be done?

Comment: Do you mean you want to use a dictionary to extract the words?

Comment: what criteria are you using? Should it be around 4 or 5 letters? Should they be valid words in english? What do you want to do with www.google.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest searching the domain string against a list of known words, and then using the fine php string library to break it apart.

http://wordlist.sourceforge.net/ is one source of lists of words.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try one of the hyphenation libraries mentioned in this answer:
[Wrapping a text using php, based on language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2227999/wrapping-a-text-using-php-based-on-language)

It splits up words on syllables, which is probably what you want. A dictionary approach would be more reliable I think, but has more dependencies.